# How to set Vulkan Validation Layer filter via the vk_layer_settings.txt?

Tags: vulkan

I have just activated the Vulkan [Best Practices Validation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.189.0/linux/best_practices.html) and due to that I get the following warning:

> Validation Layer(WARNING):      Validation Warning: [ UNASSIGNED-BestPractices-vkCreateInstance-specialuse-extension-debugging ] Object 0: VK_NULL_HANDLE, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_INSTANCE; | MessageID = 0x822806fa | CreateInstance(): Attempting to enable extension VK_EXT_debug_utils, but this extension is intended to support use by applications when debugging and it is strongly recommended that it be otherwise avoided.

Naturally, I don't need to see this in a debug build, so I'd like to filter this message out in debug builds. [According to the docs](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.2.189.0/windows/layer_configuration.html) one can use the message id filter with the `vk_layer_settings.txt`:

> By default, the settings file must be named `vk_layer_settings.txt` and reside in the working directory of the targeted application.

I have checked the current directory with `std::filesystem::current_path()` (pointing to `/my/project/dir/build/src/`) and put the layer settings file there, and I have also tried to put it next to the debug .exe file (at `/my/project/dir/build/src/Debug/MyProject.exe`).

The contents of my file are:

```
khronos_validation-message_id_filter = "UNASSIGNED-BestPractices-vkCreateInstance-specialuse-extension-debugging"
```

I have tried to use the id instead of the message name:

```
khronos_validation-message_id_filter = "0x822806fa"
```

Neither of the two has worked at either of the locations. How do I correctly use this filter then?

If this is in any way important, the project is build with CMake with the main file residing at `/my/project/dir/CMakeLists.txt` and the build done through

```
cd /my/project/dir/build
cmake ..
```

And finally compiling the solution via Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just had a typo in my file.

The file had to be at `/my/project/dir/build/src` (i.e. the place I got from `std::filesystem::current_path()`) and the content now is

```
khronos_validation.message_id_filter = "UNASSIGNED-BestPractices-vkCreateInstance-specialuse-extension-debugging"
```

(in my question it was `...validation_message...` instead of `...validation.message...`)

Comment: if it works now, please accept your answer so that this question is considered answered

Comment: Yeah, I have to wait 2 days to be able to do that. As soon as I can, I will.

Comment: ahh okay, sorry =)